# Retrieve data from sqlite, always return null

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have 2 columns (wordid , word) in my table. I try to retrieve word to test sqlite parts.
And the statement below always returns NULL. I'm pretty sure my database has no problem because i've tested the statement at firefox add-on (sqlite manager).

```
NSString *str;    

const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_db) == SQLITE_OK){


    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT word FROM Circle_En WHERE wordid=2"];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
            str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_db);
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Taha

Comment: Side note: that format string is completely superfluous.

Comment: You don't appear to do anything if the prepare statement failed. Log `sqlite3_errmsg` if the prepare didn't return `SQLITE_OK`. Also log something if the `sqlite3_step` returns anything other than `SQLITE_DONE`.

Answer (score 0):

you have done mistake in the column number portion.

As the word is at index(columnnumber) 1.
 so you need to have this:

```
str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
```